# Is there a way to more accurately search for a class with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this job site for a specific job title but I keep getting this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/malachi/Documents/python_projects/Practice/Jobsearcher.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(results.prettify())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'
```

I've run this same code on other websites with different class names and I got results but when I run it on the website I need it says that the class doesn't exist

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page =requests.get("https://careers.united.com/job-search-results/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(class_ = "jobTitle")
print(results)
print(results.prettify())```
````

Comment: That... error is because that page doesn't have a matching element. It's as accurate as can be.

Comment: Have you looked at the source for that page, using "View Source"?  The page is built entirely on the fly using Javascript.  The page you fetch doesn't have any job listings.

Comment: There are no HTML elements of class 'jobTitle' on that page. Therefore *soup.find()* returns None but you don't check that which inevitably leads to AttributeError

Answer (score 0):

I have changed this line of code:

```py
results = soup.find(class_ = "jobTitle")
```

to these two lines of code. I have tested them and they work for me.

```py
results = soup.find('a', attrs={'id': "job-result0"})
results = results.string
```

I use Google Chrome. It has the free extension ChroPath, which makes it super easy to identify selectors. I just right click on text in a browser and select Inspect, sometimes twice, and the correct HTML tag is highlighted.